# Retornar resultado do banco de dados somente com senha

Tags: php, mysql

É possível retornar algo do banco de dados MySQL somente com uma "senha"?

Tenho dois nomes "fulano" e "ciclano" fulano faz aniversario dia 11/07, Fulano teria que colocar seu nome e a data de aniversario para mostrar algo do banco de dados, o mesmo para o Ciclano.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM nomes";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){
    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=100>";
    echo $dado["nome"] . " ";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $dado["idade"] . " ";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: O que já tens feito ?

Comment: Bom, meu código até agora somente busca toda a tabela do mysql, vou editar a pergunta e mostrar ele

Comment: Se duas senhas forem idênticas já era, por isso normalmente utiliza-se campos com atributo `UNIQUE` como base para autenticação, para evitar problemas como este. Tens a certeza que o sistema é mesmo assim ?